# Trying to measure change in light levels over time

Tags: arduino-uno, rgb-led

I have two LDR's attached to my Arduino Uno and an RGB LED as an output component. The two LDR's are at different offboard heights in order to see the change in light between them. I want to code on Arduino so that if the difference in light between the two LDR's does not change by a large amount over a 1 hour period (i.e stays similar), it will make the RGB  LED flash. I know that I have to use an if and else statement to do this, but does anyone know how I can code it so that I can achieve the above statement?

Thanks

Comment: you need to be able to read the values of the LDRs first ....... start by reading the value of one LDR and print the value to the serial port ..... when you are successful, read values of two LDRs and print their values to serial port

Comment: The needed algorithm strongly depends on what you really want to detect. Imagine following setup: your sensors are in two dark boxes, and you are putting a flashlight into the first box. After half an hour you take out the flashlight and put it in the second box. Looking each minute at both sensors, you will have the complete hour max. difference. Looking at the whole hour, both sensors have seen the same amount of light. To help you it would be good if you give a little bit more of information what are your use cases.

Answer (score 2):

Break this into pieces. Solve the pieces one at a time.

Write code that reads the 2 photocells and calculates the difference between them. Log that difference to the console.

Then add a global variable to remember the old difference, and a max difference. Each time you take a new set of readings and calculate the difference, compare it to the old difference. If the new difference is greater than the old difference, update the max difference. Then update the "old difference" with the new reading.

Figure out how to use millis() to record a starting time, and monitor the reading difference until an hour has passed. If the reading difference is below your "large amount" threshold, start the light blinking.

Then you need to decide what to do about times greater than an hour. Do you track the max difference over the most recent 60 minutes and flash the light if it is below your threshold? Maybe save a difference reading every 5 minutes into a ring buffer with 12 entries (an hour's worth of entries) and keep checking the ring buffer for a difference value greater than your threshold? (You should be able to Google search "C ring buffer" for sample ring buffer code. It's actually quite simple to implement.

You might also want to calculate a moving average difference reading, and compare each reading to that. I recommend using an Exponential Moving Average (EMA).

I have code in my project that uses EMA to calculate a single brightness value rather than a difference, but the idea is the same. Here is an excerpt from my code:

Define a global:

```
float   photocellAverage =      0;

#define sampleCountToAverage 100  //The larger the number of samples, the more slowly the average will change with each new reading.
```

Then

```
int photocellValue = analogRead(photocellPin);
photocellAverage -= photocellAverage / sampleCountToAverage;
photocellAverage += float(photocellValue)/sampleCountToAverage;
```

For you, you'd be calculating a difference reading and an EMA of that difference reading:

```
float   photocellDifferenceAverage =      0;

int photocell1Value = analogRead(photocell1Pin);
int photocell2Value = analogRead(photocell2Pin);
int photocellDifference = photocell1Value - photocell2Value;
photocellDifferenceAverage -= photocellDifferenceAverage / sampleCountToAverage;
photocellDifferenceAverage += float(photocellDifference)/sampleCountToAverage;
```

Comment: I like the way you implemented the EMA. May I suggest for better understandig to change the naming for the difference EMA from ´photocellAverage´ to ´photocellDiffAvarage´. It took me some minutes to puzzle out that the context changed in your second excerpt. I also wonder why you are initialising with 0 instead of initializing with the first sensor value/first difference. Do you have a specific reason for that?

Comment: As for not initializing with the first value, it's laziness. I should have. It will settle out to the same value fairly quickly, after all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't whant to be annoying, but could you please  change `photocellDifferenceAverage -= photocellAverage / sampleCountToAverage;`
to `photocellDifferenceAverage -= photocellDifferenceAverage / sampleCountToAverage;`? Or I still did not understand your construct ;-)? I tried it in Excel, at the firts glance it looks like a PT1 element, is your EMA a elegant way to implement a PT1 Element or are there differences in mathematics behind?

Comment: I fixed the 2nd part of my answer. I must confess I found the code for EMA online, and adapted it to my needs. I don't know enough about the underlying mathematics to compare it to a PT1 Element. (I had to google that to learn what it is.)